# Why does $P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n) \leq e^{-Cn}$ implies that $\sum_{n\geq 1} P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n > e^{-Cn}) < \infty$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, measure-theory

In the proof of [Schwartz's Theorem](https://www.dianacai.com/blog/2021/02/14/schwartz-theorem-posterior-consistency/), the author makes the following statement

> By Markov’s inequality, the assumption $P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n) \leq e^{-Cn}$ implies that $\sum_{n\geq 1} P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n > e^{-Cn}) <\infty, $
> where
> $$
> P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n) := \int \phi_n \, d P_0^{(n)},
> $$
> $\phi_n$ is a test function and $P_0^{(n)}$ is a probability measure

However, I am not true how this is related to Markov’s inequality which is defined as $\operatorname{P}(X \geq a) \leq \frac{\operatorname{E}(X)}{a}$.

Can you please help see the connection between these two statments?

Comment: Is this is a matter of notation? $P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n) = \mathbb{E}[\phi_n]$ by definition, with respect to the measure $P_0^{(n)}$

Comment: @BenA, but then the question remains how does $\mathbb{E}[\phi_n] \leq e^{-Cn}$ imply that $\sum_{n\geq 1} P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n > e^{-Cn}) <\infty$?

Comment: @BenA, I understand the notation but I am not sure how one implies the other.

Comment: Using only the Markov inequality, I think you need more. You need something like $\mathbb{E}[\phi_n]\leq\exp(-C'n)$ with $C'>C$ so that $\sum_{n\geq1}P_0^{(n)}(\phi_n>\exp(-Cn))\leq \sum_{n\geq1}\exp(Cn)\exp(-C'n)<\infty$

Comment: I know, I was suggesting that the statement in the article doesn't follow as it is presented